# Add legend for line plot with confidence interval (geom_ribbon) and density plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot containing a line plot with confidence interval (`geom_ribbon()`) and an additional density plot of the underlying data (from a different data frame).

I would like to add a legend with three entries: for the line, the confidence interval, and the density.
Consider the following MWE: (in `t1`, `ylo` and `yup` mark the CI, `y` the line, and `t2` contains the data for the density plot.

(I tried incorporating code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47865121/create-ggplot2-legend-for-multiple-datasets) to no avail.)

```
library(tidyverse)
t1 <- tibble(x = c(0:22)) %>% 
  mutate(ylo = c(seq(from = .25, to = 1.35, length.out=10), seq(from = 1.35, to = -1.22, length.out=13)),
         y = .25 * x + 1, 
         yup = c(seq(from = 2.75, to = 4.5, length.out=10), seq(from = 4.75, to = 12, length.out=13)))
t2 <- tibble(x = rnorm(100000, 10, 1))

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = t1, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_ribbon(data = t1, aes(x=x, y=y, ymin=ylo, ymax=yup), linetype=2, alpha=.15) + 
  geom_hline(linetype='dotted', yintercept = 0) + labs(y = "Y", x = "X") + theme_bw() +
  
  geom_density(data = t2, aes(x = x), color="darkblue", fill="lightblue", linetype="dashed") +
  
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#000000", "grey60", "lightblue"), name = "Title") + # from other answer; couldn't get it to work
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.0125, 12.5), xlim = c(-0.5, 22))
```

Many thanks for any pointers! :)

Comment: what's theme_iamb

Comment: very related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349206/add-legend-to-ggplot2-line-plot

Comment: @tjebo whoop, thanks - that's a costum theme. Corrected it. :) Also thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Legends appear only for aesthetics. You need to pass color, fill, linetype, alpha, etc. etc. etc into your call to `aes`.

You can use either columns programmatically, i.e. pass unquoted column names (usually preferred), but you can also just pass a character string, which will then create a discrete aesthetic, which you can then scale as usual with scale_?aes_...

Below I just added title and label to the character vectors just to make it clear where the names come from.

```r
library(tidyverse)
t1 <- tibble(x = c(0:22)) %>% 
  mutate(ylo = c(seq(from = .25, to = 1.35, length.out=10), seq(from = 1.35, to = -1.22, length.out=13)),
         y = .25 * x + 1, 
         yup = c(seq(from = 2.75, to = 4.5, length.out=10), seq(from = 4.75, to = 12, length.out=13)))
t2 <- tibble(x = rnorm(100000, 10, 1))

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = t1, aes(x=x, y=y, lty = "myline-label")) + 
  geom_ribbon(data = t1, aes(x=x, y=y, ymin=ylo, ymax=yup, fill = "MyCI-label"), linetype=2, alpha=.15) + 
  geom_hline(linetype='dotted', yintercept = 0) + labs(y = "Y", x = "X") +
  geom_density(data = t2, aes(x = x, color="MyDens-label"), fill="lightblue", linetype="dashed") +
  scale_linetype("Myline-title") +
  scale_fill_discrete("MyCI-title") +
  scale_color_manual("MyDens-title", values = c("Darkblue"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>